# Detail in Hartshorne lemma IV 4.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne *Algebraic geometry* chapter IV lemma 4.2 there is an elliptic curve $X$ (I don't think it's important here) and a separable morphism $g:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree 2. As a result there is a non trivial element $\sigma$ of $\text{Gal}(K(X)/K(\mathbb{P}^1))$.

Problem: then the author says that $\sigma$ interchanges the two points of each fiber. Why?

Idea: denoting $\mathcal{O}_P$ for the local ring of $X$ at $P$, $g(P)=Q$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{O}_P\cap k(t)=\mathcal{O}_Q$ (with notation $K(\mathbb{P}^1)=k(t)$). As $\sigma(\mathcal{O}_P)\cap k(t)=\mathcal{O}_P\cap k(t)$ then the action of $\sigma$ over points stay on the same fiber. My problem is when there is two points $P$ and $P'$ over a point $Q\in\mathbb{P}^1$, why should we have $\sigma(\mathcal{O}_P)=\mathcal{O}_{P'}$?

Comment: Is there a reason you have accepted but not upvoted the answer below?

Comment: @KReiser there isn't and it's done now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick an affine patch of the curve to work in and then the points in a fiber correspond to prime ideals of the coordinate ring of the elliptic curve in that patch. Since the Galois action is transitive on the prime ideals lying above a common prime (in this case $P,P’$ lying above $Q$), the non-trivial element is forced to switch them.

Since the Galois group is so small, we can do a simple argument for the transitivity. Pick an element $x\in P \setminus P'$ which exists since $P$ and $P'$ are assumed distinct. Then the element $x\sigma(x) \in P \cap k(x) = Q$ as it is stable under the Galois action. But then $x\sigma(x) \in P'$ as well since $P'$ lies above $Q$. As $P'$ is prime, this means that either $x\in P'$ or $\sigma(x) \in P'$. As the former isn't possible, it has to be the case that $\sigma(x) \in P'$.

Comment: I think OP is asking *why* the Galois action is transitive on those prime ideals.

Comment: @KentaS I see, I think you're right. It's been so long since I did that proof. Ash's notes have a proof here in 8.1.2:https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter8.pdf

Comment: @Arkady your answer would be much stronger (and probably more helpful to the OP) if you added some of that material to the post :)

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the encouragement. I think a lot of Ash's argument can be stripped off if we only care about $|G| = 2$. I've added it above.